# C++ destroys itself by detecting compile errors in the standard library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, ninja, visual-studio-2022

I can't build the project in the **Debug** configuration due to the fact that the compiler detects strange compile errors in the standard library. The project can be built in the **Release** configuration,  due to the absence of `_DEBUG`, but I need to debug the project somehow. How can it be fixed?

Example (`<atomic>`):

```
#ifndef _INVALID_MEMORY_ORDER
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _INVALID_MEMORY_ORDER _STL_REPORT_ERROR("Invalid memory order")
#else // ^^^ _DEBUG / !_DEBUG vvv
#define _INVALID_MEMORY_ORDER
#endif // _DEBUG
#endif // _INVALID_MEMORY_ORDER
...
inline void _Check_memory_order(const memory_order _Order) noexcept {
    // check that _Order is a valid memory_order
    if (static_cast<unsigned int>(_Order) > static_cast<unsigned int>(memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        _INVALID_MEMORY_ORDER; // C2660 C2059 C2143
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
>------ Build started: Project: CMakeLists, Configuration: Debug ------
  [1/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\input.c.obj
  [2/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\egl_context.c.obj
  [3/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\vulkan.c.obj
  [4/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\null_init.c.obj
  [5/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\init.c.obj
  [6/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\monitor.c.obj
  [7/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\osmesa_context.c.obj
  [8/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_joystick.c.obj
  [9/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\context.c.obj
  [10/158] Building C object CMakeFiles\glew.dir\externals\glew\src\glew.c.obj
  [11/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\window.c.obj
  [12/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\null_monitor.c.obj
  [13/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_module.c.obj
  [14/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\null_joystick.c.obj
  [15/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_thread.c.obj
  [16/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\null_window.c.obj
  [17/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\platform.c.obj
  [18/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_time.c.obj
  [19/158] Building RC object externals\glew\CMakeFiles\libglew_shared.dir\build\glew.rc.res
  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
  
  
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  
  
  
  
  [20/158] Building RC object externals\glew\CMakeFiles\libglew_static.dir\build\glew.rc.res
  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
  
  
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  
  
  
  
  [21/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_init.c.obj
  [22/158] Linking C static library glew.lib
  [23/158] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\openal-soft && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -D "GIT_EXECUTABLE=C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe" -D LIB_VERSION=1.21.1 -D LIB_VERSION_NUM=1,21,1,0 -D SRC=C:/Users/maxiemar/source/repos/breakout/externals/openal-soft/version.h.in -D DST=C:/Users/maxiemar/source/repos/breakout/build/vs/x64-Debug/externals/openal-soft/version.h -P C:/Users/maxiemar/source/repos/breakout/externals/openal-soft/version.cmake"
  [24/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\almalloc.cpp.obj
  [25/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_monitor.c.obj
  [26/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\wgl_context.c.obj
  [27/158] Building C object externals\glfw\src\CMakeFiles\glfw.dir\win32_window.c.obj
  [28/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\alstring.cpp.obj
  [29/158] Linking C static library externals\glfw\src\glfw3.lib
  [30/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\ringbuffer.cpp.obj
  [31/158] Building C object externals\glew\CMakeFiles\libglew_shared.dir\src\glew.c.obj
  [32/158] Building C object externals\glew\CMakeFiles\libglew_static.dir\src\glew.c.obj
  [33/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\polyphase_resampler.cpp.obj
  [34/158] Linking C static library externals\glew\lib\glewd.lib
  [35/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\alcomplex.cpp.obj
  [36/158] Linking C shared library externals\glew\bin\glew-sharedd.dll
  [37/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\alfstream.cpp.obj
  [38/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\dynload.cpp.obj
  [39/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\threads.cpp.obj
  [40/158] Building CXX object externals\openal-soft\CMakeFiles\common.dir\common\strutils.cpp.obj
  [41/158] Linking CXX static library externals\openal-soft\common.lib
  [42/158] Generating hrtf_default.h
  [43/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\graphics\Texture.cpp.obj
  [44/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\input\InputManager.cpp.obj
  [45/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\graphics\Shader.cpp.obj
  [46/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\utils\FileManager.cpp.obj
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/breakout.dir/src/utils/FileManager.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1430~1.307\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DGLEW_STATIC -IC:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\glew\include -IC:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\openal-soft\include -IC:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\glm -IC:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\stb -IC:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\glfw\include -IC:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\externals\openal-soft\include\AL /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++17 /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\utils\FileManager.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\breakout.dir\ /FS -c C:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\src\utils\FileManager.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(206): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(206): error C2660: '_invalid_parameter': function does not take 2 arguments
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(348): note: see declaration of '_invalid_parameter'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(206): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(206): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(221): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(221): error C2660: '_invalid_parameter': function does not take 2 arguments
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(348): note: see declaration of '_invalid_parameter'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(221): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(221): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(237): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(237): error C2660: '_invalid_parameter': function does not take 2 arguments
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(348): note: see declaration of '_invalid_parameter'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(237): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(237): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(297): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(297): error C2660: '_invalid_parameter': function does not take 2 arguments
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(348): note: see declaration of '_invalid_parameter'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(297): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'string'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\atomic(297): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
  [47/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\Window.cpp.obj
  [48/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\graphics\SpriteRenderer.cpp.obj
  [49/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\ResourceManager.cpp.obj
  [50/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\game\GameObject.cpp.obj
  [51/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\graphics\ShaderProgram.cpp.obj
  [52/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\game\GameLevel.cpp.obj
  [53/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\Game.cpp.obj
C:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\src\graphics\Font.h(6): warning C5208: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes
C:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\src\Game.cpp(65): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'GLint', possible loss of data
C:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\src\Game.cpp(68): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'GLint', possible loss of data
  [54/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\game\Brick.cpp.obj
  [55/158] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\breakout.dir\src\game\Ball.cpp.obj
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(breakout)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCES src/main.cpp src/WindowManager.cpp src/WindowManager.h src/Window.cpp src/Window.h src/graphics/Shader.cpp src/graphics/Shader.h src/graphics/ShaderType.h src/graphics/ShaderProgram.cpp src/graphics/ShaderProgram.h src/utils/FileManager.cpp src/utils/FileManager.h src/graphics/Texture.cpp src/graphics/Texture.h src/ResourceManager.cpp src/ResourceManager.h src/input/InputManager.cpp src/input/InputManager.h src/input/EventHandlers.h src/Game.cpp src/Game.h src/game/GameState.h src/graphics/SpriteRenderer.cpp src/graphics/SpriteRenderer.h src/Singleton.h src/game/GameObject.cpp src/game/GameObject.h src/game/Brick.cpp src/game/Brick.h src/game/GameLevel.cpp src/game/GameLevel.h src/game/Player.cpp src/game/Player.h src/game/Ball.cpp src/game/Ball.h src/physics/Direction.h src/physics/Collision.h src/physics/CollisionDetector.cpp src/physics/CollisionDetector.h src/graphics/Particle.h src/graphics/ParticleEmitter.cpp src/graphics/ParticleEmitter.h src/graphics/PostProcessor.cpp src/graphics/PostProcessor.h src/graphics/PostProcessingEffect.h src/game/PowerUp.cpp src/game/PowerUp.h src/game/PowerUpType.h src/utils/Random.cpp src/utils/Random.h src/audio/AudioManager.h src/audio/AudioManager.cpp src/audio/AudioFile.h src/graphics/TextRenderer.h src/graphics/TextRenderer.cpp src/graphics/Font.h src/graphics/GlyphInfo.h src/AssetsLoader.cpp src/AssetsLoader.h)

# GLFW build configuration

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(externals/glfw)

# end
# ------------------------
# GLEW build configuration

add_subdirectory(externals/glew)
include_directories(externals/glew/include)
add_library(glew STATIC externals/glew/src/glew.c)
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)

# end
# ------------------------
# OpenAL build configuration

add_subdirectory(externals/openal-soft)
include_directories(externals/openal-soft/include)

# end
# ------------------------
# Header-only libraries

include_directories(externals/glm)
include_directories(externals/stb)

# end

add_executable(breakout ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(breakout glfw glew OpenAL ${OPENGL_LIBRARY})
```

#### Update

In general, I can't find anything that could cause such errors.

**FileManager.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "../audio/AudioFile.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class FileManager {
public:
    static std::string readAsText(const std::string& path);
    static std::vector<unsigned char> readAsBinary(const std::string& path);
    static unsigned char* readImage(const std::string& path,
                                    GLint width,
                                    GLint height,
                                    GLint components,
                                    bool flip = false);
    static AudioFile readOggFile(const std::string& path);
};
```

**AudioFile.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

struct AudioFile {
    int channels;
    int sampleRate;
    int samples;
    std::unique_ptr<short> data;

    int getSampleCount() const {
        return channels * samples;
    }
};
```

**FileManager.cpp**:

```
#include "FileManager.h"
// STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION must be defined in *.c or *.cpp file (not in header)
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <stb_vorbis.c>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

std::string FileManager::readAsText(const std::string &path) {
    std::string content = "";
    std::ifstream file(path);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        // Read file's buffer contents into stream
        stream << file.rdbuf();
        file.close();
        // Convert stream into string
        content = stream.str();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open text file " << path << std::endl;
    }

    return content;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> FileManager::readAsBinary(const std::string& path) {
    std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open font file " << path << std::endl;
    }

    auto size = file.tellg();
    auto bytes = std::vector<unsigned char>(size);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bytes.front()), size);
    file.close();

    return bytes;
}

unsigned char* FileManager::readImage(const std::string& path,
                                      GLint width,
                                      GLint height,
                                      GLint channels,
                                      bool flip) {
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(flip);
    auto image = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, 0);
    if (image == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open image file " << path << std::endl
                  << "Reason: " << stbi_failure_reason() << std::endl;
    }

    return image;
}

AudioFile FileManager::readOggFile(const std::string& path) {
    AudioFile audioFile;
    short* output;
    audioFile.samples = stb_vorbis_decode_filename(path.c_str(),
                                                   &audioFile.channels,
                                                   &audioFile.sampleRate,
                                                   &output);
    audioFile.data = std::unique_ptr<short>(output);

    return audioFile;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you have a bad header in your code before you include some header in the standard library. Check the `C:\Users\maxiemar\source\repos\breakout\src\utils\FileManager.cpp` file since it appears the problem originates there.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried to find problem cause but i still see nothing (upd). I don't even use <atomic> in my code.

Comment: <atomic> is probably used in several git modules, but I can't imagine how they could be so broken.

Comment: What are lines 206 and 221 in atomic? In Visual Studio 2019 the lines you showed in your snippet of it start at line 44.

Comment: Four possibilities, in order from most likely to least likely. (1)  One of your headers or source files has bad code (or macros that clash with standard library headers). (2)  One of the headers for the third-party libraries you are using has bad code (or macros that clash with standard library headers) (3)  Your installation is broken.  (4)  You have found a bug.  Eliminate possibilities (1) and (2) first.  Address (3) by reinstalling your compiler/IDE/libraries.  I wouldn't bet on (4) but, if the problem still isn't fixed, report a bug to Microsoft, and wait patiently for a solution.

Comment: *"I can't find anything that could cause such errors."* -- you could try removing stuff until the error goes away. Since the error appears to be in header files, a quick way to start is to reduce `FileManager.cpp` to just the `#include` lines and verify that the problem persists (recompile; your first error should be unchanged). Then comment out the `#include` lines one by one to get a minimal set of headers that reproduces the problem. *Or... try again tomorrow. Some people with strange errors like this see them go away after restarting their computer.*

Comment: Including a c or cpp file is never a good idea, i haven't looked through the whole of `stb_vorbis.c` but there are various `#define`s that could cause problems for the standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the problem was in the `stb_vorbis.c` file, whose `#define`'s conflict with the standard library. I discovered this by isolating from **stb** and then going to this file.

I was inspired by the solution [here](https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio/issues/73).
It was suitable to me to rearrange `#include` directives in such a way that `stb_vorbis.c` was at the end of the list. Now it is possible to build the entire project completely.

**FileManager.cpp**:

```
#include "FileManager.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

// STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION must be defined in *.c or *.cpp file (not in header)
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>

#define STB_VORBIS_HEADER_ONLY
#include <stb_vorbis.c>
#undef STB_VORBIS_HEADER_ONLY
```

Comment: Including a **source** file via `#include` directive smells a lot. Including **C** source file in **C++** smells even more. Why do not compile `stb_vorbis.c` **separately** instead of including it?